# grocery crud add button to copy row in another table

Tags: grocery-crud

I have 2 tables: **customers** and **standby** and I added a new button into my grocery crud in standby in that way:

```
$crud->add_action('Send', '', 'standby/copyrow','ui-icon-plus');
```

Both tables have the same fields, in standby I receive data from a form and the idea it's when I click "Send" copy that id ino customers and delete that id from standby

In other words I need to add a row from the first table (where I added a new button) into the second one, and then delete that row from the first table.

then I created a function

```
function copyrow($id)
    {
       // I don't know how can I add that row 
    }
```

Hope someone can help me, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Tables that i used in this code:

First table name - customers
  and    Fields - a(primary key,auto increment), b

Second table name - standby
  and    Fields - c(primary key,auto increment), d

Make changes to your code that you want..

function copyrow($id)
{

```
      $customers=$this->db->select('b')->where('a',$id)->get('customers')->result();
      foreach ($customers as $customer)
      {
              $this->db->set('d', $customer->b); 
              $this->db->insert('standby');
              $this->db->delete('customers', array('a' => $id)); 
      }
```

}

I sure that you will help this code.